# At The Square Brackets

Tags: riddle, poetry, computer-science

> The sky is so clear
>   As if I am in emptiness.
>   "Insert coin here"
>   Says the arcade just emplaced.
>   I will bring my eraser
>   If my paper is swapped with a scrap.
>   Nothing to extract from the scrap
>   Since they'll merge together anyway.
>   I count and find
>   The supremum and the infimum.
>   At the square brackets
>   I begin and end.

What am I?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are a:

> Map
>
>  Because each line refers to one or more member functions of a C++ std::map.

The sky is so clear

> clear()

As if I am in emptiness.

> empty()

"Insert coin here"

> insert()

Says the arcade just emplaced.

> emplace()

I will bring my eraser

> erase()

If my paper is swapped with a scrap.

> swap()

Nothing to extract from the scrap

> extract()

Since they'll merge together anyway.

> merge()

I count and find

> count() and find()

The supremum and the infimum.

> These are terms for [particular elements of a set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum), in this case the keyset of the map, which are related to upper_bound() and lower_bound()

At the square brackets

> The square brackets operator [] looks up an element of a map, as does the at() function.
>
>  Thanks to OP and Gareth for correcting me on this, because I originally answered "set" but of course you can't look up anything in a set using [] or at().

I begin and end.

> begin() and end()

Comment: rot13(Ree... Lbh zvffrq bar pyhr. Naq fgq::frg qbrfa'g unir bcrengbe [].)

Comment: rot13(V guvax lbh npghnyyl jnag n fgq::znc, naq gur "ng" va gur gvgyr vf nabgure pyhr.) Making this a comment rather than another answer because clearly you've basically got it and it seems churlish to come and snipe after the fact :-).